# MVC .Net nested projects

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

We are in the process of a website redesign, and we'd like to transition over to MVC. It's a very large website, and our current situation is we have a root project, then we have sub-projects nested inside it for each of our departments. This way each department can be recompiled separately. Using virtual directories in IIS, we are also able to have a single Master Page in the root project, which all the other projects use (all our pages are currently ASPX). The downside to this virtual directory solution is that the root master page is not available to the sub-projects when debugging them. We'd like to switch to MVC, and hopefully MVC can solve this issue.

For the new website, I have created an MVC project that will serve as the root project. I have a shared layout all ready to go, but I'm having a couple of big problems:

1. I can't figure out a workable way to create nested MVC
   projects for each department. I have tried a number of different
   ways, but I always end up with a 403 error. I was able to create
   Areas within the root project and this worked, but this will not
   allow us to recompile individual Areas, which is a must, as our site
   is simply too large.
2. How to share the layout in the root with all the
   department projects (even during debugging) without relying on IIS virtual directories. I
   tried using Razor Generator, but it seems a little too complicated
   for me, and I could never get anything to work, or even figure out if it is capable of doing what I need.

Any advice would be much appreciated. MVC for .Net seems pretty useless for large sites if there is no way to separate sections into other projects that can be compiled individually.

Comment: This is where asp.net mvc Areas shine.

Comment: Can you compile Areas individually? Because if not, this won't work for us.

Comment: Areas abstract routing and project organization based on code responsibilities such as MyApp/Accounting, MyApp/Inventory MyApp/HumanResource each area can be worked on as an individual MVC application and bought together into one application using a shared code base. There is no way to compile an area as it just another abstraction to routing but nothing prevents you from breaking up you libraries to match your conceptual areas.

Comment: @lrb - I understand Areas, but the fact that they can't be compiled separately is a huge problem. Our site is way too large to have to recompile the entire site for a small change in one of our department Areas. You say "but nothing prevents you from breaking up you libraries to match your conceptual areas" but I don't understand what that means. I've tried creating sub-folders and projects for each department within in the root project, but it doesn't work. It's like MVC won't recognize these sub-directories as valid parts of the site, all I get are 403 errors.

Comment: @tjc59 - There is such a thing as portable areas, but they have their own issues and really should only be used when you need a modular approach, like a plug-in architecture where you ship components separately.  Not a good fit for an enterprise.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - 403 errors. I have separate MVC projects for each department, and set up IIS virtual directories for each department, and set up the routing in each department's routingconfig to account for the virtual directory, but all I get are 403 errors and no info on how to resolve them.

Comment: @tjc59 - 403 errors are permissions errors, you only get those when you don't have access to something which means either a folder or file permission problem, or an authentication problem.  Why would you create virtual directories?  MVC doesn't use a folder structure, it only uses routes.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - I understand 403, but it is not a permissions or authentication problem. The department folders have all the same folder permissions and authentication as the root of the site, because the department projects are nested within the same parent folder as the root project.

Comment: @tjc59 - You don't use virtual directories in MVC, you specify areas as paths in your routes.  You can compile your controllers and models into separate assemblies, which are referenced in your routing configuration.  virtual directories do not come into it.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Can you point me to any examples of this somewhere? I have been searching all week and haven't seen any actual working examples.

Comment: @tjc59 - If you're fine with your Views being in the main project (remember, views aren't compiled), then you only need to create a separate class library project file and put your controller and model classes in that.  The Route Configuration is what does all the work of hooking up the request with the objects, and it doesn't care whether something is in an external dll or not as long as it's referenced in the project.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Good point, I will try that out. Thanks!

Comment: @tjc59 - the only trick is that you may have to use the namespace parameter to MapRoute to add the namespace if it's in a different namespace.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate how this is done.  Here's a snapshot of a test project I just threw together.  The 403's you were getting were most likely because IIS is configured to no list the contents of folders, and those virtual directories had nothing in them.

The important thing here is that the Controllers and models are in  a separate project.  And your views are in your main project.  It's much more difficult to try and package the views into your external projects.  It can be done, but the thinking these days is that you would create nuget packages to deploy your areas to production (which means you end up with all your views together in production anyways).

This is a good first step for you.  If you find this isn't enough, then you can look at other methods.  But try to make this work for you first.

The other piece you need to do is change your AreaRegistration (which also stays in your main site, though you could figure out a way via Dependency Injection  to make these work in the separate projects)

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            // add controller = "yourcontroller" for default controller for area
            new { controller = "Some", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new [] { "YourExternalProjectNamespace.Controllers" } <-- This gets added
        );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the assistance. I tried this but couldn't get it to work, kept getting 404 errors. But the more I look at it, I don't think this is the way we want to go.

Comment: We ended up figuring out how to get things working by making completely separate MVC projects nested inside the root MVC project and not using Areas (each project is configured as an application in IIS), the 403 errors were simply an issue with the routing config. And to get the shared layout, I think we are just going to create post-build events to copy down the layout files to all the department projects. I think this is going to be the only way we can get everything we want.

Comment: @tjc59 - I promise you, it works exactly as I just showed you.  My test project I built in 2 minutes works.  You get the 404 errors because you most likely did not add the namespace like I pointed out above in the route registration.  Or you did not add the default controller action for the area.

Comment: I added the namespaces and the default controller action.

Comment: @tjc59 - Well, the test project I shows you works.  I don't know what you're doing wrong.  Do you have custom routing?

Comment: I don't know, I did everything exactly as you did, and it's not working. Regardless, I don't think this setup is going to work for a site as large as ours. The department projects need to be able to be debugged completely independently of the root project. It seems like using Areas would require you to always debug the root project in order to debug the department projects.

Comment: @tjc59 - You can always create a shell solution with an empty root site to do debugging... it's trivial

Answer (score 0):

In our soultion, we have a separate project for the presentation layer (MVC web site) that relies on DLLs compiled in other projects for individual areas (disciplines) and core classes (e.g., core repositories, security classes, domain models).

The areas are designed to use base classes that then reference the core or specific classes defined in the other libraries.  We make heavy use of interfaces and generics to boilerplate most of the basic functionality in the presentation layer, and then extend it where necessary.